# Jasper Report php shrink the detail band or extend the detail band without page break

Tags: jasper-reports

Good day to all the programmers out there, I'm having trouble to make a single thermal receipt using the Jasper Report where I crawl all over the internet but the solution is not working on my site.

[image]

This is just a very simple template I make before the full version,
Below is what I required

1. page header static
2. detail will dynamic print and shrink or extend base on the data
3. page footer static

but somehow, the result is like:-

[image]

The detail band will never shrink even I have choose the **Remove Line When Blank**, split type: stretch

Below is the source code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.10.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.10.0-unknown  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="cs_receipt" pageWidth="186" pageHeight="760" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="186" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="370ce1d5-e26a-4656-894d-25de1a48e2c1">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT TOP 5 DOCNO FROM tblso]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DOCNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="102" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="36" width="100" height="30" uuid="c37e86f3-9393-43d3-b088-e3089d135239"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Header]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="96" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="50" y="10" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e642c8fc-f87d-4b0f-bac9-37a35a8b5d57"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DOCNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="106" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="2fd94017-7ee5-4ff3-844c-94d4a4966169"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Footer]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to fix design - the report contains a lot of free space and page size is also wrong

Comment: the problem is the data in the detail band is dynamic, mean that it can be 20 lines or it can be only 1 line, so I want the free space to shrink or extend base on the detail band's content row